# Disabling jQuery for specific element?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile and need it to not apply jQuery to a specific form element.  I can see in the jQuery it does target this specific element.  It applies an effect I don't want applied.

Is there some way to do this?  I have tried using `style=` inside the element but the jQuery seems to override this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute `data-role="none"` to the dom element you don't want enhanced.